# Build is Success but No sources to compile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

Maven test output in the Eclipse console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for Mabi:Mabi:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.45.0 @ line 20, column 21
    [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin @ line 74, column 10
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
    [WARNING] 
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Mabi 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Mabi ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\workspace\Mabi\src\com.TestCase
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ Mabi ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 166 source files to E:\workspace\Mabi\target\classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Mabi ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\workspace\Mabi\src\test\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Mabi ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ Mabi ---
    [INFO] No tests to run.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 7.287 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-23T11:32:40+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/283M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Above image shows the directory of my project but when I run the project via Maven it gives me the above result without running the test. Looking forward for some accurate solutions.

And this is what my POM.XML file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Mabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>Mabi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.40.2</version>

    </dependency>             
        <dependency>              
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
            <version>2.45.0</version>                               
        </dependency>                          
        <dependency>              
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
            <version>6.8</version>                                                                   
       </dependency>              
</dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/com.TestCase</directory>
        <includes>
        <include>**/com.*TestCase.java</include>
        </includes>
        </resource>    
     </resources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     <plugin>


        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)?

Comment: I'm currently using the standard method which is src-->test-->java files

Comment: Follow the conventions and remove ` sourceDirectory`, and your `resources` entries in your pom file. Tests are usually name like `*Test.java` and **NOT** `*TestSuite.java` ...and furthermore if you use testng you seldom need to define a suiteFile...surefire plugin will handle that all fine..If those tests are integration tests than you should name them like `*IT.java` and use the maven-failsafe-plugin...and follow the name schema...

Answer (score 14):

Maven is all about ["convention over configuration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) idiom. In order that `maven-surefire-plugin` will run your testcases it expects to find it under `src/test/java`, hence, you should follow the maven's standard directory layout and put all your test cases under `src/test/java`.

[image]

Comment: Saved me another hour of going crazy \o/

Comment: Thanks, I glad it helped!